# Find file and rename it BASH

Tags: bash

Any idea why this is not working? I checked many links and I can't figure it out why I think the syntax is correct.
I want to find the file maplist.txt.old and then rename it to maplist.txt in the same folder. I got no errors.

```
find ~ -type f -name csgo/maplist.txt.old -execdir mv csgo/maplist.txt.old maplist.txt \;
```

Comment: csgo/maplist.txt.old is invalid, you must use the file name not a piece of path

Comment: You need to match the full path, with something like `*csgo/maplist.txt.old`.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to handle this.  Since you are looking in **~/csgo** you can go directly to the directory in the find.  The *-execdir* option will run the command in the directory.  So without changing your example much:

```
find ~/csgo -type f -name maplist.txt.old -execdir mv maplist.txt.old maplist.txt \;
```

To automate this a bit further, you may want to handle this with a bash *for* loop, for example:

```
for file in $( find ~/csgo -type f -name maplist.txt.old ) ; do
  mv $file $( echo $file | sed -e 's/\.old//' )
done
```

Comment: I don't understand what the benefit of the loop is, it does the same as your first command, but is much less robust (breaks for filenames with blanks, has unquoted expansions, could be simplified to use parameter expansion instead of `echo | sed`, the sed command should escape `.` and anchor `old` at the end of the string...)

Comment: The advantage is that you only have to name the file once, and you can adjust it more easily for other files in the future.

Comment: You could use this instead: `-execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.old}"' _ {} \;`

Comment: Yes, this expands to `mv filename.txt.old filename.txt`, where `$1` is `filename.txt.old`.